# Web2py storing sql values in a list

Tags: python, web2py

```
def addtocart():
    if request.vars.product:
        myrecord = db(db.PetProducts.product_number==request.vars.product).select(db.PetProducts.product_name)
        session.productList.append(myrecord)
    return show()
```

I would like something like this, the ability to store a result of a query in a list. In this case a product name.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to do it;

```
def addtocart():
    if request.vars.product:
        for row in db(db.PetProducts.product_number==request.vars.product).select():
            session.productList.append(row.product_name)
    return show()
```

There had to be a for loop involved, I was uner the impression the query did a loop automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can try session.productList.extend(db(db.PetProducts.product_number==request.vars.product).select().as_list())

Answer (score 0):

```
def addtocart():
    if request.vars.product:
        myrecord = db(db.PetProducts.product_number==request.vars.product).select(db.PetProducts.product_name).first()
        session.productList.append(myrecord.product_name)
    return show()
```

I'm guessing you're trying to append only a single result from your query. This will do the job